# Can I get a decimal number does not contain a similar consecutive double-digit???

Tags: calculus

By using the WolframAlpha, I couldn't get a decimal number(not rational) not contain a similar consecutive  double-digit.I checked all the common numbers ( $\pi$ , $e$, Golden ratio,$\sqrt{2}$, and so on)

I put two examples to illastrate the question

$\pi$

[image]

$e$

[image]

Comment: Try 1/7. You might also look up **normal numbers**.

Comment: Try $12/99 = 0.12121212...$

Comment: There are many, Eg:$ 0.123123123..., 0. 1010101010....$

Comment: These are rational numbers

Comment: What's wrong with rational numbers?

Answer (score 3):

There are infinitely many numbers that do not contain a digit twice in a row. The comments give several examples.

However, [normal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number) will have about 1/10th of the places as a digit followed by the same digit. Also, the sequence $11$ will be found in 1/100 places, and so on.

A theorem says that "almost all" real numbers are normal. That means if you take any interval such as $[0,1]$ and choose a real number in that interval at random (with uniform probability), the probability that your number is not normal is zero. So, the probability of choosing a number without repeated digits is zero, even though there are infinitely many such numbers. So it makes sense that the numbers that you choose all have repeated digits. The odds are not in your favor!

---

Here is an irrational number without repeated digits:
$$0.123121231212123121212123\ldots$$

The sequence $12$ is written once, then twice, then thrice, and so on, with the digit $3$ between those sequences. There is no infinite repetition, so this number is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

For an irrational example, try $.2020102010102010101020\ldots\ldots$, i.e. every odd-numbered digit is a $1$ or $2$, every even-numbered digit is $0$, and the number of $1$'s between $2$'s increases by one each time.

EDIT: This does have a "closed-form" expression: it is
$$ \dfrac{10^{1/4}}{20}\theta_2\left( 0,1/10 \right) +{\frac {
10}{99}}$$
where $\theta_2$ is a Jacobi theta function.  Here it is in [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E%281%2F4%29%2F20%20*%20Theta2%280%2C1%2F10%29%20%2B%2010%2F99).

Answer (score 0):

Many rational numbers will satisfy your request.  You can construct an irrational that does, too.  Start with the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) $0.12345678910111213141516\dots$ and delete any repeated digit, getting $0.123456789101213141516171819202123\dots.$  I don't know if it has a name.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{7} = 0.\overline{142857}$

No repeated decimals.